# What's wrong with this code to replace NA values?

Tags: mysql

```
WITH sub1 AS (
        SELECT 
            AVG(CAST(Age AS INT)) AS Avg_Age
        FROM `Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event`
        WHERE Age <> 'NA'),
    sub2 AS (
        SELECT 
            AVG(CAST(Height AS INT)) AS Avg_Height
        FROM `Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event`
        WHERE Height <> 'NA'),
    sub3 AS (
        SELECT 
            AVG(CAST(Weight AS INT)) AS Avg_Weight
        FROM `Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event`
        WHERE Weight <> 'NA')

SELECT
    CASE WHEN Age = 'NA' THEN sub1.Avg_Age
         ELSE Age END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Height = 'NA' THEN sub2.Avg_Height
         ELSE Height END AS Height,
    CASE WHEN Weight = 'NA' THEN sub3.Avg_Weight
         ELSE Weight END AS Weight
FROM `Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event`;
```

Comment: Its difficult to read your code, but it appears as if you never select anyting from your cte:s

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Remove the conflicting tag.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: A `SELECT` does not change anything.  To "replace", you need an `UPDATE`.

Comment: What's wrong? The main mistake is incorrect datatype for `Age` column in the table structure (everything claims that it is VARCHAR) which does not match the type of the data stored in it. You must alter the datatype for this column to some INT (TINYINT UNSIGNED seems to be enough), and use NULL for non-specified values instead of textual `'NA'`.

Answer (score 0):

Does "replace" mean to change NA to a number?  If so, I would do it with 3 `UPDATEs`.  But I don't want to discuss that; I want to question the task.  Will a new row ever be added?  If so, the averages are no longer correct and it is no longer possible to "fix" the NA rows.

If, on the other hand, you left the NAs, you could correctly fetch the provided value *or* the averages.  Maybe this is what you meant by "replace"?  If so, I would toss the WITH.  Instead simply JOIN to a single query that computes all averages.  But first, I would use NULL instead of NA.

```
SELECT  name,
        COALESCE(Age, avg_age),
        COALESCE(Height, avg_height),
        COALESCE(Weight, avg_weight)
    FROM (
        SELECT  AVG(Age) AS avg_age,
                AVG(Height) AS avg_height,
                AVG(Weight) AS avg_weight
            FROM Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event`
         ) AS averages
    JOIN Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event;
```

If that gets in some kind of syntax problem, then it may need a `LATERAL JOIN` (if that is available in the version you are using) or a `WITH` for the subquery.

Another approach:

```
SELECT  AVG(Age),
        AVG(Height),
        AVG(Weight)
    INTO @avg_age, @avg_height, @avg_weight
    FROM Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event;

SELECT  name,
        COALESCE(Age, @avg_age),
        COALESCE(Height, @avg_height),
        COALESCE(Weight, @avg_weight)
    FROM  Olympics_Data.Athlete_Event;
```

Note `NULL` makes it possible to use `AVG()` without worrying about testing for NA.

Yes, you could do that with NA; change the 3 AVG() calls:

```
        AVG(NULLIF(Age, 'NA'));   -- (etc)
```